# wrong output while invoking the palindrome function through another program

Tags: python, palindrome

I am trying to solve this problem

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is `9009 = 91 × 99.`

Below is the code I have used to find if a number is Palindrome.

```
 #largest product of two  digit no.s  which is a palindrome eg 91*99 = 9009
        def check_palindrome(str):
            x = len(str)
            for i in range(x//2):
                if str[i] == str[x-1-i]:
                    flag = 0
                else:
                    flag = 1
            if flag== 0:
                print "palindrome"
            else:
                print " not palindrome"
        check_palindrome('9009')
i= 91
j= 99
product = i* j
print product
check_palindrome('product')
```

When i invoke the function check_palindrome() after calculating product, the program gives wrong output while it gives the correct output when called individually.

Comment: Don't use Python keywords or function names for you variable names - like [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str). - maybe use `s` instead. It can cause wierd hard to find errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the literal *string* `"product"`, which is not a palindrome, to your palindrome function:

```
check_palindrome('product')
```

Remove the single quotations and convert to a string:

```
check_palindrome(str(product))
```

to pass the string representing the integer stored in `product`.

---

As an aside, here is an easy way to test if a string is a palindrome:

```
def check_palindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]
```

which compares the reverse of the string `s` with itself. It's a palindrome if both are equal.